# How to compute the rotation turning one orthogonal pair of vectors into another such pair?

Tags: vectors

Two pairs of mutually orthogonal 3-dimensional vectors of unit length are given: $(n_1,n_2)$ and $(m_1,m_2)$:

$n_1 \cdot n_2 = 0$

$m_1 \cdot m_2 = 0$

Obviously, rotation exists that, when applied to $(m_1,m_2)$, makes $m_1$ parallel to $n_1$ and $m_2$ parallel to $n_2$.

Is it possible to express this rotation vector through $n_1,n_2,m_1,m_2$ using only the following operations:

- summation/subtraction
- multiplication by a scalar
- scalar multiplication of vectors
- vector multiplication of vectors

?

Comment: Rotation matrix is in 1-to-1 correspondence with a vector along the axis of rotation, which length is equal to the rotation angle.

Comment: What is the dimension of the ambient space?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, it is 3. I will correct the question.

Comment: Does "scalar multiplication of vectors" mean the dot product, and "vector multiplication of vectors" mean the cross product ?